# Choosing the right Google Analytics API metrics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm looking to get the number of unique users at any one time, in addition to the total number of unique users across 24 hours. For the former, I'm using rt:activeUsers.

The thing is, when looking at the graphs on Google Analytics, it doesn't make sense to me to just add up the active users at any one time because if you get 16 visitors at 9:00 and they stay on the site all day, the next data point at 10:00 should be zero because there are no new users, only the 16 currently on. However, the data never goes to zero on Google's graphs, meaning new people are always visiting between each data point, which I know isn't right.

It's hard to explain, but I'm sure you understand what I'm getting at. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the question, but I believe that  ga:users metric is what you're looking for and just set the 24 hour time frame in to your query.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=user&jump=ga_users